# How I get value of tempdata["value"] in a variable by using jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am Trying to Get TempData Value in Variable by using jQuery

```
$("#save").click(function () {
  alert("ok")
  var tran = '@TempData["m_pran"]';
  @*var ptran1 = $('@TempData["m_pran"]').val().trim();*@
  if (tran) {
    alert(tran)
  } else {
    alert("Not Get tran ");
  }
});
```

Comment: That looks correct to me. Are you using this in external js file or .cshtml file?

Answer (score 1):

You need to put parenthesis around the value as:

```
$("#save").click(function () {
  alert("ok")
  var tran = '@(TempData["m_pran"])';

  if (tran) {
    alert(tran)
  } else {
    alert("Not Get tran ");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It is correct if your script in cshtml file.
If you separate the script to script file.

You should use `input tag` with `type hidden` to store temp value.

In cshtml file

```
<input type="hidden" id="m_pran" value="@TempData["m_pran"]"/>
```

In js file

```
$("#save").click(function () {
  alert("ok")
  var tran = $('#m_pran').val();

  if (tran) {
    alert(tran)
  } else {
    alert("Not Get tran ");
  }
});
```